# FFMPEG gif resizing not working while I am adding watermark

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to resize video to gif image. But everytime i am getting failure.

Please check my cdde:

```
$input = "files/video.mp4";
$thumbnail = 'img/logo.png'
$output = 'gif/'.time().'.gif';

$command = "ffmpeg -t 3 -ss 00:00:02 -i $input -i $thumbnail -filter_complex overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5 -codec:a copy $output"
@exec($command, $ret);
print_r($ret);
```

Above command I am not getting array result. But working fine. My video successfully converted to GIF with watermark. But if I am trying to resize below code. This command not working. Please tell me where is error

```
$command = "ffmpeg -t 3 -ss 00:00:02 -i $input -vf scale=400:-1 -i $thumbnail -filter_complex overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5 -codec:a copy $output"
```

Please help me. Let me know if any other way to make video to gif with resize and watermark image.

**EDIT:** If I am removing watermark command. Then my resize GIF working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaling should occur within the complex as well.

```
ffmpeg -t 3 -ss 00:00:02 -i $input -i $thumbnail -filter_complex [0]scale=400:-1[b];[b][1]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5 -codec:a copy $output
```

Else the standalone `vf` output is mapped for output by ffmpeg.

---

FFmpeg offers palettegen and paletteuse filters for optimized GIF generation.

```
ffmpeg -t 3 -ss 00:00:02 -i $input -i $thumbnail -filter_complex [0]scale=400:-1[b];[b][1]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5,split[v][p];[p]palettegen,fifo[pal];[v][pal]paletteuse -codec:a copy $output
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code working fine. But my GIF resolution quality not looking good. can you please help me.