# ffmpeg-Error "Buffer queue overflow, dropping." when merging two videos with delay

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to merge two videos (as example the iphone video from https://peach.blender.org/trailer-page/). The videos are placed on an background image with the overlay filter and the second video starts 3 seconds later.

And I need that the audio is mixed.

Here is my code:

```
ffmpeg \
    -loop 1 -i background.png  \
    -itsoffset 0  -i trailer_iphone.m4v \
    -itsoffset 3  -i trailer_iphone.m4v \
    \
    -y \
    -t 36 \
    -filter_complex "
        [2:a] adelay=3000 [2delayed];
        [1:a][2delayed] amerge=inputs=2 [audio];
        [0][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,33)' [lv1];
        [lv1][2:v] overlay=10:300:enable='between(t,0,36)' [video]
    " \
    \
    -threads 0 \
    -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" \
    -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac \
    merged-video.mp4
```

I get the error message:

```
[Parsed_overlay_3 @ 0x7fe892502ac0] [framesync @ 0x7fe892502b88] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
```

And the merged video has many dropped frames.

I know that are some other posting with this error message. But the suggested solutions doesn't work for me.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What suggested solutions have you tried?

Comment: I tried `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS`for the audio channels, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FFmpeg is dropping frames from `[2:v]` because the processing of `[0][1:v]overlay` is taking longer than the frame drop threshold.

Insert a fifo filter to 2:v to avoid this.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png
       -itsoffset 0 -i trailer_iphone.m4v
       -itsoffset 3 -i trailer_iphone.m4v
       -t 36 -filter_complex
         "[2:a]adelay=3000[2delayed];[1:a][2delayed]amerge=inputs=2[audio];
          [0][1:v]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,33)'[lv1];
          [2:v]fifo[2f];[lv1][2f]overlay=10:300:enable='between(t,0,36)'[video]"
       -threads 0 -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac merged-video.mp4
```

(For stereo audio, it should be `adelay=3000|3000`)

Comment: It works great. Thank you! I never used the `fifo`-filter before.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ("the processing of [0][1:v]overlay is taking longer than the frame drop threshold"), it really helped. I ran into this error when generating a GIF. The fix was to generate the palette in a separate command before using the palette to generate the GIF.

Comment: For GIF, it can be done in a single command with a FIFO filter after the palettegen.

Comment: @Mulvya I tried that, but fifo wouldn't accept the output of palettegen (probably because that output is a picture, not a video). I can't remember the exact error message off the top of my head though.

Comment: Did you use it like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38131468/5726027 ?

Comment: Something like that... don't remember the exact command anymore though. This was just for a one-off.

Comment: FWIW I had to do it again, and this time I figured it out. The fifo filter has to go after the split filter, between the video stream and the paletteuse filter which consumes that video. The fifo filter only accepts one stream, so you have to be sure _only_ the video stream is getting passed to fifo, not the output from paletteuse. E.g. `split[x][z];[z]palettegen[y];[x]fifo[a];[a][y]paletteuse`